# search for long contiguous repeated substrings

Tags: python, algorithm, substring

I have a string of 0s and 1s. Define a "contiguous-double" as a substring that repeats itself immediately. For example the string "011101010101110" can be broken up to "011 1010 1010 1110" which can be compressed to "011(1010)1110".

Is there a good algorithm to find all contiguous-doubles in a string? The best I could come up with is quadratic with respect to the length of the string:

```
def all_contiguous_doubles(s):
    for j in range(len(s)):
        for i in range(j):
            if s[i:j] == s[j:2*j - i]:
                print "%s(%s)%s" % (s[:i], s[i:j], s[2*j - i:])
```

Comment: There can be quadratically many doubles. Consider the string "111...111"

Comment: The way to avoid quadratic behavior in any kind of string search is to skip prefixes. But this is much less useful in strings with only two character values, so it may be a bad tradeoff.

Comment: what is the character range of the expected string?

Comment: Every four-bit string contains at least one double, so there are always at least `n/4` doubles in any length-n string of zeroes and ones.

Comment: @Jan, good call. My interest in finding contiguous-doubles was to find the longest one, which I presumed would be by iterating through all of them. I am now thinking that this presumption is false.

Comment: You can let a regex engine do the dirty job of finding the longest double starting at some location for you: `/(.+)$1/`

Comment: The regex idea is brilliant @JanDvorak. Thank you!

Comment: @wye.bee if you are willing to trade off code simplicity for performance, build a suffix tree and pick the the deepest branch.

Answer (score 1):

Here I present my dynamic programming solution which has time complexity of **O(n^2)** and
space complexity of O(n^2) where n is the length of original string.

Below I define function dl(r,c) recursively.
If you make dl(r,c) a table and **fill it in the correct order**, you'll complete it in O(n^2).

definitions:

> char(i) = character at position i
>
> substr(i) = substring starting from position i towards the end of original string.
>
> dl(r,c) = length of common, non-overlapping prefix of substr(r) and substr(c).

recursive definitions of dl(r,c):

> Since dl(r,c) is symmetric, we will only consider r <= c.
>
> dl(r,c) = 0 when r == c.
>   Because if the substring starts at the same point, it will always be overlapping.
>
> dl(r,c) = 0 when char(r) != char(c).
>   Because the prefix is not the same.
>
> ```
> if char(r) == char(c),
>     if dl(r+1,c+1) + 1 < c-r
>         dl(r,c) = dl(r+1,c+1) + 1
>     else
>         dl(r,c) = dl(r+1,c+1)
> ```

The maximum of `dl(r,c)` which has `dl(r,c) == c-r` will be your answer.

Comment: Space complexity can be reduced to `O(n)` with careful management.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the regex jan mentions `/(.+)$1/`

Here is a simplistic algorithm that would probably work otherwise:

create a function

```
get_largest(string, i, j)
```

which returns the largest double between i and j.

I would use a hash_size of min(20, (j-i)//2)

now say your hash_size is 20, find the most infrequent substring of length 20 and all the positions in which it occurs. (this can be done quickly with a hash table)

now lets say the positions it was found are [10, 110, 320, 500, ..]
look at string[10:110], string[110, 320], string[320, 500].. etc.
If any of these sub strings occur multiple times, find all positions of these substrings and check for a double using your technique above or a modified version of it.

If you still haven't found a double that contains the most infrequent substring of length 20, we can now recursively divide and conquer to search all the longest substrings that don't contain the most infrequent substring.

Hopefully in most cases this should be fast.

Answer (score 0):

If compression is really your final goal :

Why not have a lookup-table of size 16  mapping the strings  "0000"  "0001"  , "1010" etc  to their respective  hexadecimal number ' 0-F'  ?

When you are storing the representation:  convert binary string to  a sequence of  hexadecimal string?

You might also want to lookup on [Grey Code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code).  where in a binary sequence, the previous number and current differ  by  exactly 1 bit.

If we have the Grey Code representation of 0-F in table, then :

For letter in the hexadecimal string :  check if the previous or current  letter is the corresponding one  in 'Grey code' order.  If so, you can compress it further .  ( the differing bit can be in the middle too- some cases have to be handled properly' )